# Runtime 50290 error When trying to enter Time value in a Range

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, runtime-error

I am building a userform to track the time it takes to do something and compare that to how long it should have taken.

My code runs most of the time but once in a while I will encounter a Runtime 50290 error when trying to enter a time value in a range.

```
Dim TargetRow As Integer
TargetRow = Sheets("Engine").Range("B3").Value + 1 'engine B3 is current amount of entries in form  

Dim TargetRow2 As Integer
    TargetRow2 = Sheets("Engine").Range("I3").Value + 1

txt_Material1.Value = Sheets("RPRT").Range("C5").Offset(TargetRow - 1, 0).Value
txt_Hose1.Value = Sheets("RPRT").Range("C5").Offset(TargetRow - 1, 1).Value
txt_Quantity1.Value = Sheets("RPRT").Range("C5").Offset(TargetRow - 1, 2).Value

'Runtime 50290 error occurs at line of code below
Sheets("RPRT").Range("C5").Offset(TargetRow - 1, 3).Value = "'" & Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

lbl_PlanTime = Format(Sheets("RPRT").Range("C5").Offset(TargetRow - 1, 6).Value, "hh:mm:ss")
lbl_Timer = "00:00:00"
timer = True

Do While timer 'allows the timer to start counting
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
    DoEvents
    lbl_Timer = Format(DateAdd("s", 1, lbl_Timer), "hh:mm:ss")
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and provide feeback:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With Sheets("RPRT").Range("C5").Offset(TargetRow - 1, 3)
        .Value = Now 'Here check if the right cell get the right value
        .NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I added the code but it will still bug once about every 10-15 runs. It now highlights the;

.Value = Now 

line of code